# Sublime Text always outputs html with pandoc instead of running python code

Tags: python, html, sublime-text-3, pandoc

As it says in the title, when I try to run some python code ([this](https://dev.to/bilal_io/website-screenshots-with-selenium-in-python-kcn) code specifically), sublime text will create an html markdown file with pandoc.

The specific error message I receive is

```
/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test8.utf8.md --to html4 --from 
markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+sm
art --output test8.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --
standalone --section-divs --template 
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmarkdown/r
md/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable 
'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header 
/var/folders/3l/yhb2ls7d0ysdq3qxqrk0yk6w0000gn/T//RtmpN2bKeX/rmarkdown-
str182e0169376a2.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-
url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-
MML_HTMLorMML' --metadata pagetitle=test8.utf8.md 

Output created: test8.html
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Yes, I use R and Rmarkdown at times but I don't have the slightest clue why sublime text doesn't just execute my python code when I hit command+b.

Sublime text is built 3207. I use Mac OS X 10.15 Beta. I use python3 and manage my packages with anaconda.

Please let me know what else would be relevant to troubleshoot this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Sublime Text tries to determine automatically which Build System to use. When there are multiple build systems installed, that are intended for the same file type, it can lead to unwanted results. Fortunately, you can override the automatic setting and specify which build system to use for the current document.

[image]

Comment: Very helpful. I thought that once I selected view>syntax>python I would be in the clear.